# use wp_footer and wp_head as a variable in wordpress function

Tags: wordpress

I cannot figure it out

```
if ($opt['position'] == "header") { $position = 'wp_head'; } elseif ($opt['position'] == "footer") { $position = 'wp_footer'; }
add_action($position, 'popunder_ads');
```

I'm trying to change the position from heade rto  footer using a button_set field via redux framework but it `$position` doesnt work, the function popunder_ads is working fine if I add directly wp_footer or wp_head in action

Any one has any idea? Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think `$position` doesn't work in some case, replace `elseif` with `else`, like this, `$position` will be `wp_head` or `wp_footer` and will always be set if `$opt['position']` is not retrieve.

Try to update your question with more context about where you are running your code. Does `$opt` is accessible to your script ?

Try the following code, put it in functions.php of your child-theme.

```
add_action('init', 'so_41240459');

function so_41240459(){
    // if $opt come from theme option
    $opt = get_option('your_theme_option_name');

    if ($opt['position'] == "header") { 
         $position = 'wp_head'; 
    } else(
         $position = 'wp_footer'; 
    }
    add_action($position, 'popunder_ads');

}
```

Comment: if I use only else one of the first if option is not working its remaining allways in the else

Comment: Yes, but you need to close your conditional with an else to set $position in any case and make you script works.

Comment: yes, I tried that to but when I switch the option `$opt['position'] == "header"` in redux framework to header instead of the footer option its still showing else it doesnt change

Comment: Are you sure that $opt is define ? Does $opt comes from a get_option or from a global value ?

Comment: yes the option is define I thought it too and checked many times but I was not sure if the wp_footer and wp_head can be used as variable in add_action

Comment: Yes, usually they can be set like that. How do u get $opt ? Update your question with the related code, it will easier to figure what's happen.

Comment: Other point : the best is to put your code in a function and trigger it with another action, add_action('init', 'yourfunction'); . With this, you'll be sure that the hook will be define before its call.

Comment: yesw I will try that thankyou, the function Im calling from redux framework with buttons_set field using a ID with two sub ids called header and footer as you see in the if statements

Comment: Benoti I did how you told me created a new function and pasted the codes in this function than created a new add_action with init and it worked fine. Thankyou verymuch